# Importing text into a JTable is not displaying

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have created a program where I can input data in JTextField and on hitting save button I use a JFileChooser to save the data in a `.txt` file where each JTextField is in a new line. I also created a button that pops up a JFileChooser to browse for that file and populate its corresponding cells.

I am new to GUIs, the code I wrote is not working. I tried different variations and cannot seem to get it. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

The input is

```
 john
Doe
st. Jude
100
```

Here is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.util.Scanner
import java.util.Vector;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.*;

//import javax.swing.filechooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

public class Charity 
{
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Learning Team Charity Program");
    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Charities
    final String[] charityArray = {"St.Jude", "CHOC", "Cancer Research", "AIDs Foundation", "Crohns Foundation"};
    final JComboBox selector = new JComboBox(charityArray);
    JPanel first = new JPanel();
    first.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    first.add(selector);

    // User input JLabels and JTextFields
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("First Name: ");
    final JTextField name = new JTextField();
    JLabel lastLabel = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
    final JTextField lastname = new JTextField();
    JLabel donationAmount = new JLabel("Donation Amount: ");
    final JTextField donation = new JTextField();


    JPanel second = new JPanel();
    second.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
    second.add(nameLabel); second.add(name);
    second.add(lastLabel); second.add(lastname);
    second.add(donationAmount); second.add(donation);


    // Donate & Exit Buttons
    JButton donateButton = new JButton("Donate");
    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    JButton openButton=  new JButton("Open File");
    JPanel third = new JPanel();
    third.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    third.add(donateButton);
    third.add(saveButton);
    third.add(openButton);
    third.add(exitButton);

    // JTable display
    final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    model.addColumn("First Name");
    model.addColumn("Last Name");
    model.addColumn("Charity");
    model.addColumn("Donation");

    table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);      
    JScrollPane scrollPane = JTable.createScrollPaneForTable(table);

    JPanel fourth = new JPanel();
    fourth.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    fourth.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Button Events
    exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.exit(1); 
        }
    });

    openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JFileChooser openChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int openStatus = openChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(openStatus == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try{
            File myFile = openChooser.getSelectedFile();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

            String line;        
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
                             model.addRow(line.split(","));           

                    }//end while
                      br.close();
                }//end try

                catch(Exception e2){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Buffer Reader Error");
                }//end catch
            }
        }


        private void setValueAt(String line, int row, int col) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int status = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text", ".txt", "txt"));
                //fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter("txt"));
                PrintWriter output;
                try {
                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    output = new PrintWriter(file +".txt");
                    for(int row = 0; row<table.getRowCount(); row++){
                        for(int col = 0; col<table.getColumnCount();col++){
                            output.println(table.getValueAt(row, col).toString());

                        }
                        output.println();
                    }

                    output.close();

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

});
    donateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##,###.00");
            try 
            {

                Object[] rows = new Object[]{name.getText(), lastname.getText(), selector.getSelectedItem(),
                    donation.getText()};
                    model.addRow(rows);
                    name.setText("");
                    lastname.setText("");
                    donation.setText("");
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a Dollar Amount", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    // Frame Settings
    frame.setSize(470,300);
    //frame.setLocation(300,200);
    cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    cp.add(first);
    cp.add(second);
    cp.add(third);
    cp.add(fourth);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }   
}
```

Comment: Use a DefaultTableModel and call its `addRow(...)` method to add rows. Also, don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Thank you. I understand I have to pass a value in the parenthesis after the addRow. I have done it in the button that saves the data into the text file. I am just not able to figure out what to pass in order to display the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks for all those that tried to help.

```
openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JFileChooser openChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int openStatus = openChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(openStatus == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try{
            File myFile = openChooser.getSelectedFile();
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
                             Scanner br = new Scanner(new FileReader(myFile));
            String line;        
        while((line = br.nextLine())!= null){
                        Object[] myRow = new Object[]{line,br.nextLine(), br.nextLine(), br.nextLine()};
                             model.addRow(myRow);
                            // line = br.readLine();
                                if(br.nextLine()== " "){
                                    line=br.nextLine();
                                }
                    }//end while
                      br.close();
                }//end try

                catch(Exception e2){
                     return;
                }//end catch
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Not a very good solution. You should not just use the readLine() method like that. If you don't have the right number of lines in the file you will generate an IOException. If you have and empty line you will also likely generate an IOException. Row data should be treated as row data, which means each row should be one line in the file. You should then use a delimiter (other than " ") to separate each column value and use the split() statement as I demonstrated below. You are still using "==" for a String comparison even though the first comment told you not to do this.

Comment: There are somethings that I still cannot fully comprehend. I am only 3 weeks into GUIs. I have changed the code in the program to have the .equals(). As far as the empty lines, I separate each set of entered data by an empty line and I have not gotten any errors. I put code to skip an empty line and read from the next.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand I have to pass a value in the parenthesis after the addRow.

People don't know what that means because the code you posted here doesn't have an addRow(...) method.

I see you posted a second question 2 hours later:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951407/how-to-properly-read-a-txt-file-into-a-a-row-of-a-jtable.

Keep all the comments in one place so people understand what is going on.

Also, posting a few random lines of code doesn't help us because we don't know the context of how the code is used. For example, I have no idea what how you created the "model" variable. I don't know if you ever added the model to the table.

Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when posting a question so we have the necessary information. The file chooser is irrelevant to the problem because we don't have access to your real file. So instead you need to post hard coded data. An easy way to do this is to use a `StringReader`.

Here is a working example that shows how to read/parse/load a file into a JTable:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 4);

            String data = "1 2 3 4\na b c d\none two three four";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new StringReader( data ) );
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] split = line.split(" ");
                model.addRow( split );
            }

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            add( new JScrollPane(table) );
        }
        catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

All you need to do is change the code to use a FileReader instead of the StringReader.

Comment: Thank you. I have made some of the changes as you noted but I still get the same thing. I have updated the code to have everything so you can see better all of what I have. I need them to display horizontally in one row, all they do now is display vertically in one column.

Comment: @sammyb123, You have not posted a SSCCE (you posted your entire application which is not relevant to the stated question) Did you look at the format of your input file? How is the data in your file different than the data in my StringReader? If all your items are displayed in one column that is probably because you save each column of data in a separate row. If you want all the columns in one row, then save the data in one row, which means you need to use `print(...)` for the first three columns and then `println(...)` for the last column.